# AWS CLI - Why do my S3 bucket files look like they're encrypted?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I'm using S3 to host a static website, with a fairly standard config - a bucket with a bunch of HTML/JS/CSS files, public read access enabled, and Static Website Hosting enabled.

Accessing the website via the URL or S3 Endpoint works fine:

- https://www.tearelaw.co.nz/
- http://www.tearelaw.co.nz.s3-website-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com

However, when trying to download files from the bucket via a command like `aws s3 sync s3://www.tearelaw.co.nz ./`, the files come out looking like gibberish. Opening the files in UTF-8 format gives me a bunch of random characters [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRDav.png), which leads me to believe that they *might* be encrypted (or just corrupted in-transit?).

Downloading another bucket on the same AWS account, using the same command and AWS config, works absolutely fine. It seems to be *just* this bucket.

So far, I've tried:

- Opening the files in various formats (UTF-8, UTF-16 LE/BE, etc).
- Checking that Default Encryption is *disabled* on the bucket.
- Checking that object-level Encryption is *disabled* on the `index.html` file.
- Downloading using different `--region` variants.

I'm using the latest version of the AWS CLI (`aws-cli/1.17.13 Python/3.6.0 Windows/10 botocore/1.14.13`), on a Windows 10 PC.

Is there some bucket-level encryption option I'm missing?

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that your files are being provided in **gzip format**. This is common on websites to minimise bandwidth requirements. The web browser knows how to unzip the contents.

I did the following on a Mac (sorry, I know you use Windows):

```
aws s3 cp s3://www.tearelaw.co.nz/static/img/logo.min.png .
mv logo.min.png logo.min.png.gz
gunzip logo.min.png
```

The `logo.min.png` file could then be opened as a normal png.

The same goes for the web pages themselves:

```
aws s3 cp s3://www.tearelaw.co.nz/practice-areas/index.html .
mv index.html index.gz
gunzip index
```

The `index` file was then readable as a text file containing HTML.

Why is it in this format? Well, whoever put the files in the Amazon S3 bucket probably did it intentionally, or used a utility that used `gzip` to compress them.

Comment: Thank you very much John! I've checked my static website build script, and it does indeed pre-gzip all of the files before uploading them to S3. The files are all opening correctly now. That was a real head-scratcher!